# How to create horizontal div moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know please, how to create a div moving horizontal.

For ex:
http://usbek-et-rica.fr

Are there many prepered div which moving by .animate() function?
I want to understand how does it works.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Use the source, luke. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/0600a29256be76bd87adb547545bf7219fafb6ee/src/effects.js#L79 There's a timer, a tick callback, and it updates the position to the next progressive offset each time around.

Answer (score 1):

`animate` function simply changes continually css values.

```
$('#your-div').animate({
    left: '+=500', // move 500px to the right
}, 5000, function() {
// Animation complete.
});
```